# Too Many Arguments in C++

Tags: c++, arguments

I am facing difficulties in my C++ code. I am a beginner. Like, only with very basic knowledge of C++. So, I really can't figure a way to do this. I thought of making an RPG game using C++ commands and am close to finishing it. But somehow, I couldn't make a constant health for the hero. Taking a look at the code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>



using namespace std;


class player
{   public:
    int health = 100;
};

int battle();
void death();

int main()
{
   int abc;
   player hero;
   hero.health = abc;
   int a;
   int replay = 1;
   cout << "You have 100 Hp. \n";
   while (replay == 1)
{

srand(time(0));
cout << "\n Press 1 to move forward; 2 To stay. \n";
cin >> a;
    if (a == 2)
    {
        if (rand() % 4 + 1 != 1)
        {
            cout << "You stay at your place. \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Enemy Attacks! (20 Hp) \n";
            //battle(hero.health);
            //cout << "\n Press 1 to continue. \n";
            cout << "\n Do you want to play again? Press 1 to replay and 0 to quit.\n";
            cin >> replay;
        }
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        if (rand() % 2 + 1 != 1)
        {
            cout << "You moved forward. No one around. \n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You move forward. Enemy attacks! (20 Hp) \n";
            battle(abc);
            cout << "\n Do you want to play again? Press 1 to replay and 0 to quit.\n";
            cin >> replay;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry. Please enter a valid move. \n";
    }

}

return 0;
}

int battle(int x)
{
   player enemy;
   enemy.health = 20;
   player hero;
   int y;


while (enemy.health >= 0)
{
int eattack = rand() % 15 + 7;
int attack = rand() % 10 + 1;
int escape = rand() % 4 + 1;
cout << "\n Press 1 to attack. 2 to flee \n";
cin >> y;
if (y == 2)
    {
      if (escape != 1)
      {
        cout << "Can't escape! \n";
        cout << "Enemy attacked! Dealing a damage of: " << eattack << " Hp. \n";
        hero.health = hero.health - eattack;
        cout << "Your Hp is: " << hero.health;
      }
      else
      {
        goto Aftermath;
      }

    }
else if (y != 1)
    {
        cout << "Sorry. Please enter a valid response. \n";
    }
else
    {
        cout << "You attack the enemy. \n";
        cout << "You deal a damage of: " << attack;
        enemy.health = enemy.health - attack;
        if (enemy.health >= 0)
        {
            cout << "\n Enemy attacks you, dealing: " << eattack << " Hp damage.";
            hero.health = hero.health - eattack;
            cout << "\n You have: " << hero.health << " Hp left.";
        }
    }

if ((hero.health <= 0) || (hero.health == 0))
    {
        death();
        enemy.health = -1;
    }
}

if (hero.health > 0)
    {
        cout << "\n Enemy fainted!";
        //cout << "You found Hp Potion! Your Hp was refilled.";
    }

   Aftermath:
      if ((hero.health > 0) && (enemy.health > 0))
       {
          cout << "Escaped Successfully! \n";
       }

     return x;

  }
 void death()
    {
      cout << "You died!";
    }
```

As you see, I have called for `battle(abc)` and `battle(hero.health)` [which I have commented for now] but the problem is, it says "Too many arguments to function `int battle()`. Previously, I simply avoided parameters and created object "hero" in the battle method itself. But every time you get through a battle sequence, it comes back and declares it again, thus making its health refill. [Look at `if (hero.health > 0)` ]

I really don't know about global variables and all that. I just want to know if there is a workaround or a way to solve this parameter problem. Any other suggestions to have health as a 'constant' and not declared every time is also warmly accepted. Thank you so much!

P.S. Suggestions for shortening the code also accepted but please, I am a beginner. So advanced strategies are beyond my skills right now. I take time to grasp concepts.

Comment: abc is not initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the function before the `main` method, and then you implement the function after the `main` method.

The problem is, you implement the function as:

```
 int battle(int x)
```

but this doesn't match your declaration:

```
 int battle();
```

Just change your function declaration block so the `battle` function matches the expected signature:

```
int battle(int x);
void death();
```

---

That will get your code compiling, but you are still a number of steps from getting this to work.

I'll give you one starter: instead of passing in the hitpoints into `battle`, pass the entire player.

```
 void battle(Player &player)
 {
     // ...
 }
```

Then you can modify the player's hitpoints directly in the `battle` function.

You would then call this with:

```
 battle(hero);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The code now works! I am new here and actually didn't expect a quick answer. Thanks! If there are future problems, I will let you know in the question itself!

Comment: @SabeshBharathi Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have another problem, you should ask a different question. rather than modifying this one. Good luck with your journey! Also, if this answer solved your problem, please press the Tick button next to the answer.